# Username and Password login for ASP.NET MVC SSL Connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl

I created an MVC web application that was using a MSSQL database store for username and password.  This is not the out of the box solution that comes in the Visual Studio template.  I just attached a new SSL certificate to the application, and I also added the [RequiresHttps] attribute to the neccessary controllers.  Now when I go to the website it is asking me to login, but the login that I use to use that is store in the MSSQL database is not the same that it is looking for.

Can someone please inform as to what I need to look at searching for on Google in order to find a solution for a username and password store for the new SSL connection.

### EDIT

None of my logs are getting into the database.  I am requesting a URL of https://www.example.com/User/SignIn, which gets redirected to https://www.example.com/User/SignIn?ReturnUrl=%2fUser%2fSignIn

So, to me it does not look to be getting to my Action, but it does.  Not sure how this is going.

Comment: The web application was working as it should for a username and password.  I added the SSL certificate to the web application.  Now, when I browse to the website it pops up a dialog asking for a username and password for the site, but it is not using the username and password store that is currently setup in the MSSQL database.  What is the new SSL certificate looking for when it is asking me for a username and password, and what is the best practice for setting the solution up?

Comment: adding SSL should not make any difference to how you are implementing the login. did you make any other changes? Is it the browser's login dialog?

Comment: Not that I can imagine would change the login procedure.  I am using a controller to call the `[HttpPost] Login` action.  Is there a reason the application would not know how to route the Post of the username and password?

Comment: Does the login dialog appear on every page or just the page that has the login action?

Comment: It appears on any page if the user is not authorized because of the [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: Is it the browser login dialog box?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5159/discussion-between-bdparrish-and-dallas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the [RequiredHttps] attribute because I am not looking for a two-way certificate communication.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem has nothing to do with the SSL/encrypted connection. Can you debug and have a look what credentials are POSTed to your AccountController (or whatever you named it)?

Whether or not the you're using SSL, your authentication logic shouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Does the site allow anonymous access? If not this would explain why a login dialog would be displayed.